# how to convert/calculate nvarchar to int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to convert nvarchar(12) to int so i can use it in my code-behind, the data in my column is time related (HH:MM) as below:

```
00:02
00:55
01:22
05:16
```

I would like to convert it to be as calculated minutes :

```
2
55
82
316
```

I tried to use below sql:

```
SELECT LTRIM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, column1)) 
FROM tstable
```

but it gives below error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: The code you have posted does exactly what you're saying you want it to do. The error you're getting isn't being generated by the code you're showing us. (The `LTRIM` should be wrapped around the `column1` `nvarchar` value, not around the resulting `integer` value, but it still doesn't throw any errors.) [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e8e38/1)

Answer (score 3):

The following works in SQL Server:

```
select datediff(minute, 0, '05:16')
```

So this should also work:

```
select datediff(minute, 0, column1)
```

This even works with spaces on either side of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
SELECT 
CAST(SUBSTRING(your_column,1,CHARINDEX(':',your_column,0)-1)AS INT)*60+
CAST(SUBSTRING(your_column,CHARINDEX(':',your_column,0)+1,LEN(your_column)) AS INT) AS T_MIN
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the data type is nvarchar, you could you by STRING methods:

```
DECLARE @HhMm AS NVARCHAR(12) = '05:16';
SELECT LEFT(@HhMm, 2) * 60 + RIGHT(@HhMm, 2)
```

Result as `316`

**Demo** with given sample data:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (TimeVal NVARCHAR (12));
INSERT INTO @TestTable (TimeVal)  VALUES ('00:02'), ('00:55'), ('01:22'), ('05:16');

SELECT LEFT(TimeVal, 2) * 60 + RIGHT(TimeVal, 2) AS MinutesVal
FROM @TestTable
```

Output:

```
MinutesVal
-----------
2
55
82
316
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select LEFT(Time1, 2) * 60 + Right(Time1, 2) Minutes from table6
```

[image]